# Form input to php file

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

I wish to let certain users enter some fields, which will in turn populate a (new) php file. The (new) file will be a language file containing simple array values:

```
$lang['example'] = 'text for example';
```

Basicly I will just populate the file with each row and everything seems grand. However, I need to know how to filter the inputs so that `'`, `"` and similiar stuff won't break the string and open up space for potential injections.

Since php allows a lot of ways to style your code, I'm not sure a `addslashes()` would be enough for this matter.

**How do I filter input so that it can be in strings in a php file?**

I couldn't find any other question regarding this matter, just database filtering.

**Extra information:**
I don't want any html in these boxes. It should be able to handle `'` and `"`, and the real question is can you do something like this:

```
$lang['example'] = 'hackkyyyyy
>>>
// do evil stuff
<<<
';
```

By that, I mean can you in an other way then `'` or `"` break a string in php?

Comment: urlencode() could solve some problems

Comment: Will ' and " be a part of the string?

Comment: I want them to be able to be. @GeoPhoenix You mean I should urldecode once retrieving them?

Comment: @RobinCastlin yes that's the process once you encode

Comment: "I wish to let certain users enter some fields, which will in turn populate a (new) php file" - this is highly inadvisable. Writing executable code at run-time is dangerous; even running under a service user that has access to write files to an executable location is usually considered unacceptable. There is almost always a better way to do it, keeping writable data in a different place to immutable code.

Comment: I populate the file like this at the moment:
`$str .= "$lang['{$key}' = ".var_export($value, TRUE).";\n"]`. Is there any holes in that approach? The reason I wanted it this way is because it neatly overrides my language file. Something that I can't do efficiently through database.

Comment: There's a hole if `$key` contains anything unexpected, or if there are bugs in `var_export()`, which is not designed as a security function and has had (unrelated) bugs in the past (for which reason some hosts used to disable it). But it's a more general point: it's a security principle to keep your executable code and your run-time data strongly separated. If your run-time service user even has filesystem permission to write to a file that will later get executed, then you've just escalated any file-upload bug into a full execute arbitrary code bug.

Comment: Yeah, that was mostly what I was concerned about. This solution eases things for me, but may impose a security risk. Would removing `\n` or similiar improve the safety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual I use var_export, just an exaple:

```
file_put_contents("temp.php",'<?php'. var_export($_POST,true));
```

when I need the array:

```
$a = include "temp.php";
```

Comment: This solution looks to be exactly what I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to protect against and how likely it is your code gets abused. There are quite a few ways off the top of my head:

1. addslashes() as you said in your question
2. str_replace() for each item you want to remove
3. filter_var() may be useful for you depending on a few variables

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you check my additional information, and share your thoughs?

Answer (score 0):

So you let users to fill out a form and the form values are echoed onto web page? I don't know why you couldn't simply use PHP filter functions to sanitize input and encode special characters if necessary.

- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

I also don't know why input validation/sanitization for a database wouldn't apply here. Maybe someone knows and tells...

BTW. I'm quite happy with David Power's user input validation class used in the book PHP Object Oriented Solutions. Buy the book (or visit library) and you'll be able to use the code right away.

Comment: If someone types `Don't enter`, I want it to be saved as `$lang['example'] = 'Don\'t enter'` not something which I have to encode and decode. Obviously `add_slashes()` would do the trick in this case, but I'm more curious on if there are other ways to break a `''` string.